# Redirect to original state after login using UI-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI-router, when a user goes to a page that require's a login, after they login, I would like to redirect them back to the original url they came from.

So for example,

```
/account/profile --> LOGIN PAGE (/login) --> /account/profile
/someother/requiredLogin/path --> LOGIN PAGE (/login) --> /someother/requiredLogin/path
```

My routes:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('accountProfile', {
      url: '/account/profile',
      data: {
        requiresLogin: true
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('templates/profile.html');
          }
        }
      },
    })
    .state('anotherPage', {
      url: '/someother/path',
      data: {
        requiresLogin: true
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('templates/other.html');
          }
        }
      },
    })
```

Inside my application's run block I have:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'LoginService',
    function($rootScope, $state, LoginService) {

      // Change title based on the `data` object in routes
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var requiresLogin = toState.data.requiresLogin;

        if (requiresLogin && !LoginService.check()) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('login');
        }

      });
    }
  ])
```

As you can see, I do a basic job at adding a `requiresLogin` to each route, that just redirects always to `login` route. How can I keep track of the original URL and redirect them back to it AFTER they login?

Comment: you can i.e. store current state to $rootScope

Answer (score 7):

Update your login state configuration to include default parameters for the name of the state to redirect to on login (toState) as well as any parameters passed with the original state change (toParams). If you don't define defaults, $state.params will always be empty when you check for them in your login controller - even if you provide values from your $stateChangeStart handler!

```
  .state('login', {
    data: {'requiresLogin': false},
    params: { 
      'toState': 'profile', // default state to proceed to after login
      'toParams': {}
    },
    url: 'login',
  })
```

Modify your run block to capture and pass on the requested (unauthorized) state:

```
    $state.go('login', {'toState': toState.name, 'toParams': toParams});
```

In your login controller success handler, the following will either send you to the state specified in $stateChangeStart or the default declared in your state configuration:

```
      $state.go($state.params.toState, $state.params.toParams);
```

Comment: `'profile', // default state to proceed to after login` how can I make it dynamic?